# Laravel 5.0 separated error messages for form validation

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5

I did define my validator rules like this:

```
foreach ($this->request->get('name') as $key => $val) {
            $rules['name.'.$key]    = 'required';
            $rules['phone.'.$key]   = 'required';
            $rules['comment.'.$key] = 'required';
        }
return $rules;
```

The problem is that i can't loop through, for example, name errors. All I can do is looping through them like this:

```
@foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
    {{ $error }}
@endforeach
```

I have 3 different input fields. How can I write out the errors separately beneath each input box?

Comment: I have updated my answer. If you think it answers your question, please mark it as the accepted answer by clicking the check-mark beneath its rating :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Laravel does not offer the functionality to display the error messages individually for every field. You would have to figure out a manual way of doing this if you want the feature in your application.</strike>

### Update

I don't know if this particular thing existed in earlier versions of Laravel, I sure never heard of it, but as of Laravel 5.2 you can display form validation error messages separately. [Here is a good video that demonstrates the functionality on Laracasts.](https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-2/episodes/4)

Using your example, here is what the code would look like (Without any styling):

```
<input name='name'>
@if ($errors->has('name'))
    {{ $errors->first('name') }}
@endif
```

Comment: How do i define which errors I'm looping throught in second foreach? By saying which I mean name or comment or phone.

Comment: It depends on how you want to implement it, but one solution is the one you had above. It can be improved by putting it in a function and passing the field name as an argument. I will add it to my answer.

Comment: Invalid argument supplied for second foreach. As I uderstand `$errors `variable isin't multidimention array. But i got idea behind that.

Comment: `array:6 [▼
  0 => "The name.0 field is required."
  1 => "The name.1 field is required."
  2 => "The phone.0 field is required."
  3 => "The phone.1 field is required."
  4 => "The comment.0 field is required."
  5 => "The comment.1 field is required."
]` Thats `$errors->all()` value. Index name doesn't exist.

Comment: I think I finally understand what you meant in your first post. You want to  show the validation errors next to their corresponding form elements. As far as I know, there is no standardized way of doing it. You would have to come up with your own solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your update solution works but if your validation returns more than one message it only shows the first one. If you want to give all the error information to the user you should do this:

```
@if ($errors->has('name'))
  @foreach($errors->get('name') as $error)
    {!! $error !!}
  @endforeach
@endif
```

I recommend to put this into a partial blade and `@include` it for each input you need just passing the `$errors` object and the name of the input.